# C# Threading in Window service creating issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have issue with email sending window service. The service starts after every three minutes delay and get messages that are to send from the db, and start sending it. Here is how the code looks like:

```
        MessageFilesHandler MFHObj = new MessageFilesHandler();
        List<Broadcostmsg> imidiateMsgs = Manager.GetImidiateBroadCastMsgs(conString);
        if (imidiateMsgs.Count > 0)
        {

           // WriteToFileImi(strLog);

            Thread imMsgThread = new Thread(new             ParameterizedThreadStart(MFHObj.SendImidiatBroadcast));              
            imMsgThread.IsBackground = true;
            imMsgThread.Start(imidiateMsgs);
        }
```

This sends messages to large lists, and take long to complete sending to a larger list. now the problem occurs when on message is still sending and the service get a new message to send, the previous sending is haulted and new message sending started, although i am using threads, each time service get message to send it initiate a new thread. 
Can u please help where i am doing mistake in the code.

Comment: It looks like you have a thread that uses `imidiateMsgs` but you don't have any type of thread safe locking protecting `imidiateMsgs`. If you have a good book on C# it should have a chapter on thread safety that you can study.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i will definitely follow but right now i don't have time to read a book. I need to fix this as quickly as possible. if you got the solution please help me out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like requirement is to build a consumer producer queue. In which producer will keep adding message to a list and consumer would pick item from that list and do some work with it
*Only worry for me is, you are each time creating a new Thread to send email rather than picking threads from thread pool*. If you keep on creating more and more thread, performance of your application will degrade due to over head created by context switching.

If you are using .Net framwe work 4.0, the soultion become pretty easy. You could use [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentqueue) for en-queuing and dequeuing your items. Its thread safe, so no lock objects required. Use [Tasks](http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection) to process your messages.

BlockingCollection takes an IProducerConsumerCollection in its constructor, or it will use a ConcurrentQueue by default if you call its empty constructor.

So to enqueue your messages.

```
//define a blocking collectiom
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

//Producer
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        blockingCollection.Add("value" + count);
        count++;                    
    }
});

//consumer
//GetConsumingEnumerable would wait until it find some item for work
// its similar to while(true) loop that we put inside consumer queue
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (string value in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker 1: " + value);
    }                
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since you are using FrameWork 3.5. I suggest you have a look at Joseph Albahari's implementation of [Consumer/Producer Queue](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse). Its one of the best that you would ever find out.

Taking the code directly from above link

```
public class PCQueue
{
  readonly object _locker = new object();
  Thread[] _workers;
  Queue<Action> _itemQ = new Queue<Action>();

  public PCQueue (int workerCount)
  {
    _workers = new Thread [workerCount];

    // Create and start a separate thread for each worker
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
      (_workers [i] = new Thread (Consume)).Start();
  }

  public void Shutdown (bool waitForWorkers)
  {
    // Enqueue one null item per worker to make each exit.
    foreach (Thread worker in _workers)
      EnqueueItem (null);

    // Wait for workers to finish
    if (waitForWorkers)
      foreach (Thread worker in _workers)
        worker.Join();
  }

  public void EnqueueItem (Action item)
  {
    lock (_locker)
    {
      _itemQ.Enqueue (item);           // We must pulse because we're
      Monitor.Pulse (_locker);         // changing a blocking condition.
    }
  }

  void Consume()
  {
    while (true)                        // Keep consuming until
    {                                   // told otherwise.
      Action item;
      lock (_locker)
      {
        while (_itemQ.Count == 0) Monitor.Wait (_locker);
        item = _itemQ.Dequeue();
      }
      if (item == null) return;         // This signals our exit.
      item();                           // Execute item.
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage with this approach is you can control the number of Threads that you need to create for optimized performance. With threadpools approach, although its safe, you can not control the number of threads that could be created simultaneously.

Comment: if its not infinite loop, how would you make sure your consumer thread is always processing. Events could be used to signal arrival of new items but I have not seen any producer, consumer queue with event signalling

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using your code inside a loop which **WAITS** for new messages, did you manage those waits?? let's see:

```
while(imidiateMsgs.Count == 0)
{
    //Wait for new Message
}

//Now you have a new message Here

//Make a new thread to process message
```

there are different methods for that wait, I suggest using BlockingQueues:

In public area:

```
BlockingCollection<Broadcostmsg> imidiateMsgs = new BlockingCollection<Broadcostmsg>();
```

In your consumer(thread  which generates messages):

```
SendImidiatBroadcast = imidiateMsgs.Take();//this will wait for new message
//Now you have a new message Here

//Make a new thread to process message
```

In producer(thread  which answers messages):

```
imidiateMsgs.Add(SendImidiatBroadcast);
```

And you have to use thread pool for making new threads each time to answer messages, don' initialize new thread each time.